# JSF 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3 Final <rich:fileUpload Transfer error occurred

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I don't want to persist immediately, but actually put in session and just after the user clicks on the "Upload and assign to Order" button I will start really persisting. 
some how neithe rin Chrome nor in Firefox comes the attachment add event, 
and later 
"Upload and assign to Order" button has everything null causing exception.

```
<body>
<h:form id="uploadFormId" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <rich:messages id="messages" style="font-weight:bold; color: DarkBlue; " />

    <h:panelGroup id="panelGroupId">
        <h:outputText value="Upload New Attachment"  style="font-weight:bold" />
        <br /><br />

        <h:outputText value="Doc Id" />
        <h:inputText id="DOCID" label="Doc Id:" value="#{uploadBean.docId}" required="true" style="margin-left: 10pt;"
                     validatorMessage="Doc Id must be an integer number." >
            <!-- <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="20" /> -->
            <!-- <f:validateRegex pattern="^\d+$" /> only in JSF 2.0 -->
        </h:inputText>
         <h:message for="DOCID" errorClass="error" />
        <br />

        <h:outputText value="Language" />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{uploadBean.language}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{uploadBean.languageOptions}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="defaultness_Checkbox"  title="defaultness_Checkbox"  value="#{uploadBean.defaultness}" style="margin-left: 10pt;" />
        <h:outputText value="Is Default?" style="margin-left: 2pt;" />
        <br /><br />
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:outputText value="Attachment" for="richFileUploadId" />
    <rich:fileUpload id="richFileUploadId"
                     acceptedTypes="pdf" 
                     fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.fileUploadListener}" 
                     immediateUpload="true" 
    >
    </rich:fileUpload>
    <!--
    <rich:fileUpload id="richFileUploadId"
                     acceptedTypes="pdf" 
                     fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.fileUploadListener}" 
                     immediateUpload="true" 
                     listHeight="50px" listWidth="300px" 
                     allowFlash="false"
                     addControlLabel="Add file..." clearAllControlLabel="Clear all" clearControlLabel="Clear"
                     stopEntryControlLabel="Stop process" uploadControlLabel="Upload file" 
    >
        <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" 
                     process="panelGroupId" 
                     render="attachmentUploadTableId, messages"
                     reRender="attachmentUploadTableId, messages"    
        />
        <f:facet name="label">
            <h:outputText value="{_KB}KB from {KB}KB uploaded - {mm}:{ss}" />
        </f:facet>
    </rich:fileUpload>
    -->
    <br /><br />


<!--  reRender="attachmentUploadTableId, " -->
<!--  addControlLabel="Add file..." clearAllControlLabel="Clear all" clearControlLabel="Clear"
                     stopEntryControlLabel="Stop process" uploadControlLabel="Upload file"  -->
    <a4j:commandLink reRender="attachmentUploadTableId, messages" 
                    process="panelGroupId"
                    value="Upload and assign to order"
                    action="#{uploadBean.uploadAssignToOrder}" 
                    style="  border: 1px solid #999;
                        padding:1px 4px 1px 4px;
                        color: #333;
                        background-color: #e7e7e7;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        margin-right: 10px;
                        display: inline;
                        cursor:pointer; ">
    </a4j:commandLink>
    <br /><br />

    <h:outputText value="Current Attachments" for="attachmentUploadTableId" style="font-weight: bold; " />

    <rich:dataTable id="attachmentUploadTableId" value="#{uploadBean.fileList}" var="file">
        <rich:column style="width: 50px; " >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel value="File Name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{file.filename}          " />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column style="width: 30px; " >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel value="Language" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{file.language}          " />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column style="width: 20px; " >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel value="Is Default" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{file.defaultness ? '++' : '--'}" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header" style="width: 40px; " >
                <h:outputLabel value="Details" />
            </f:facet>
            <a4j:commandLink action="#{uploadBean.deleteFile}" style="text-decoration:none; margin-left: 5pt;" value="Delete" 
                             reRender="attachmentUploadTableId" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{uploadBean.chosenFile}"
                                             value="#{file}" />
            </a4j:commandLink>
            <h:outputLabel/>
            <a4j:commandLink action="#{uploadBean.viewFile}" style="text-decoration:none; margin-left: 5pt;" value="Preview">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{uploadBean.chosenFile}"
                                             value="#{file}" />
            </a4j:commandLink>
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>

</h:form>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is the java class corresponding:

```
public class UploadBean implements Serializable {

private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger _logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(UploadBean.class);

@Autowired PdfService pdfService;
//private PdfService pdfService;

private String filename;
private String language;
private Integer docId;
private Boolean defaultness = Boolean.TRUE;
// BLOB Handling
// new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfFile.getPdf_data()), pdfFile.getPdf_data().length);
private byte [] pdf_data;

int i = 0;
private List<PdfFile> fileList = new ArrayList<PdfFile>();
private PdfFile chosenFile;

private  List<SelectItem> languageOptions = initLanguageOptions();


private List<SelectItem> initLanguageOptions(){
    List<SelectItem> list = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(3);
    list.add(new SelectItem("en", "English"));
    list.add(new SelectItem("de", "German"));
    list.add(new SelectItem("fr", "French"));
    list.add(new SelectItem("it", "Italian"));
    return list;
}

/**
 * get all files from the DB schema
 * @return
 */
    public List<PdfFile> getFileListByDocId() {
        Integer docId = getDocId();
        try {
            fileList = pdfService.getPDFFilesOnDocId(docId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _logger.error(e);
        }

        return fileList;
    }
    /**
     * get all files by DOC_ID from the DB schema
     * @param docId
     * @return
     */
    public List<PdfFile> getFileListByDocId(Integer docId) throws Exception {
        fileList.add( new  PdfFile().setLanguage("en").setFilename("first_File").setId(i++) );
    fileList.add( new PdfFile().setLanguage("de").setFilename("second_File").setId(i++) );
    fileList.add( new PdfFile().setLanguage("fr").setFilename("third_File").setId(i++) );

    //this.fileList = pdfService.getPDFFilesOnDocId(getDocId());
    return fileList;
}

// ActionEvent event EL version
public String uploadAssignToOrder(){
    //event.getComponent().getAttributes();
    System.err.println("uploadAssignToOrder...");
    _logger.error("uploadAssignToOrder...");

    PdfFile file = new PdfFile();
    try {
        String fileName = JsfUtil.PDF_FILE_PREFIX + getDocId() + "_" + getLanguage();
        Integer defaultness = Boolean.TRUE.equals(getDefaultness()) ? 1 : 0;

        file.setFilename(fileName);
        file.setDocId(docId);
        file.setLanguage(language);
        file.setDefaultness(defaultness);
        file.setPdf_data(pdf_data);

        pdfService.insertFile(file);
        this.fileList = pdfService.getPDFFilesOnDocId(getDocId());
        //fileList.add(file);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Pdf File attached for order Id:" + this.docId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Pdf File could not be attached for order Id:" + this.docId);
    }
    return null;
}

public void fileUploadListener(UploadEvent event) {
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("uploadFile starting...");
        System.out.println("uploadFile(UploadEvent event)...for Doc Id:" + this.docId);
        _logger.info("In ActionListener of file upload for Doc Id:" + this.docId);

        UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
        _logger.info("item : " + item.getFileSize() + ", " + item.getContentType() + ", " + item.getData());
        if(item.getFile() != null) {
            _logger.info("File name and size : " + item.getFile().getPath() + ", " + item.getFile().getTotalSpace());
        }

        byte [] data = new byte[item.getFileSize()];
        is = new FileInputStream(item.getFile());
        is.read(data);
        is.close();
        // save the pdf_data of byte [] for the time being
        this.setPdf_data(data);

//          PdfFile file = new PdfFile();
//          file.setLanguage(getLanguage()).setPdf_data(data).setFilename(item.getFileName()).setDefaultness(1);
//          pdfService.saveFile(file);
//          fileList.add(file);
        System.out.println("uploadFile end...");
        _logger.info("uploadFile end...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        _logger.error(e.getMessage() + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException IOE) {
            is = null;
        }
        is = null;
    }
}

public void setFileList(ArrayList<PdfFile> fileList) {
    this.fileList = fileList;
}

public List<PdfFile> getFileList() {
    //TODO  
    fileList.add( new PdfFile().setLanguage("en").setFilename("first_File").setId(i++) );
    fileList.add( new PdfFile().setLanguage("de").setFilename("second_File").setId(i++) );
    fileList.add( new PdfFile().setLanguage("fr").setFilename("third_File").setId(i++) );

    return this.fileList;
}

public String deleteFile() {
    try {
        getFileListByDocId().remove(chosenFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String viewFile() {
    return null;
}



public PdfFile getChosenFile() {
    return chosenFile;
}

public void setChosenFile(PdfFile chosenFile) {
    this.chosenFile = chosenFile;
}

public PdfService getPdfService() {
    return pdfService;
}

public void setPdfService(PdfService pdfService) {
    this.pdfService = pdfService;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return this.language;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public List<SelectItem> getLanguageOptions() {
    return languageOptions;
}

public Integer getDocId() {
    return this.docId;
}

public void setDocId(Integer docId) {
    this.docId = docId;
}

public String getFilename() {
    return this.filename;
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public byte[] getPdf_data() {
    return this.pdf_data;
}

public void setPdf_data(byte[] pdf_data) {
    this.pdf_data = pdf_data;
}

public Boolean getDefaultness() {
    return this.defaultness;
}

public void setDefaultness(Boolean defaultness) {
    this.defaultness = defaultness;
}

}
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RichFaces Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
        <param-value>50000000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RichFaces Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What exception? Where's the stacktrace?

Comment: sorry my fault, I was integrating this whole into sth. existing, and this had already form element inside. so form within form was the issue.